# How to enable pre-released updates in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

In Ubuntu I could do this in the Updates tab of Software Sources, but in Linux Mint there is no Updates tab. I just want to install kernel version 2.6.38-9.

Answer (score 1):

Mint does not publish pre-release updates [[Source](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=141&p=357647#p357647)].

Answer (score 1):

Ketchup is a update utility for linux-kernel sources
Available via the Synaptic Package or via the Terminal CLI command:

```
sudo apt-get install ketchup

~ $ ketchup -help
Usage:  ketchup [options] [ver]
 -a --archive (/home/username/.ketchup)
   cache directory
 -d --directory (.)
   directory to update
 -f --full-tarball 
   if unpacking a tarball, download the latest
 -g --gpg-path (/usr/bin/gpg)
   path for GnuPG
 -G --no-gpg 
   disable GPG signature verification
 -k --kernel-url (http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel)
   base url for kernel.org mirror
 -l --list-trees 
   list supported trees
 -m --show-makefile 
   output version in makefile <arg>
 -n --dry-run 
   don't download or apply patches
 -p --show-previous 
   output version previous to <arg>
 -q --quiet 
   reduce output
 -r --rename-directory 
   rename updated directory to linux-<v>
 -s --show-latest 
   output the latest version of <arg>
 -u --show-url 
   output URL for <arg>
 -w --wget (/usr/bin/wget)
   command to use for wget
```